# Proper approach to rebuilding video player in the list

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

I have `ExpansionPanelList` which contains number of `ExpansionPanel`s with `VideoPlayer` in its expansible part. To keep memory maintained, `VideoPlayer` is initialised and played on `ExpansionPanel` expansion and disposed on collapse.

To get and update data in the list, I am observing Firestore collection of documents using a stream. This is mandatory as list can get updated from the list screen and from further screens as well. Changes should be reflected in the list when going back through the stack.

When document in the collection on Firestore is updated while being on the screen with the list, element in the list gets updated, which triggers rebuild of the widget tree - including `VideoPlayer`.
This is unwanted behaviour, as its initialised and started on `ExpansionPanel` expand and disposed at collapse so it ends up in the "limbo" state and I need to collapse and expand it again to make it work.
Even without this additional behaviour, `VideoPlayer` would be rebuilt on every data update, which would mean restarting the video. How to prevent `VideoPlayer` from rebuilding? What would be correct flow in this case?

I have tried to extract `VideoPlayer` into separate `const` `stateless` widget and I managed to do that though widget was still rebuilding.

Comment: Do you know about Keys in Dart? This might help https://medium.com/@yetesfadev/understanding-keys-in-dart-and-flutter-use-cases-examples-advantages-and-disadvantages-efff26b2d6e8

Comment: @jbyen I've tried suggested way, thanks for the link but it still doesn't work. AFAI understand, keys preserve the State but widget rebuilds nevertheless. I ended up rewriting the logic from Stream to Future, so list screen does not rebuild "live" but only when screen is opened.